# Running the script in temporary folder

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

Is it possible to run `bash` script in a temporary folder other than the one in which it actually resides ?

My script uses a lot of filenames .I am concerned that one of the many names may coincide with others in the folder . I have named the files according to the data contained , taking reusability into consideration .

Does  `mktemp -d` and `tempfile -d` do the same ? If so , can someone please illustrate  its usage with an example.

Thanks in advance for the replies .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch directories in a running script easily. Bash has a notion of the *present working directory*, which you can change at any time. For example:

```
dir=$(mktemp -d)

cd "$dir"
echo "Current directory changed: $PWD"

cd "$OLDPWD"
echo "Back in the old directory: $PWD"
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to run bash script in a temporary folder other than the
>   one in which it actually resides?

Yes, you can use `cd` in your script to change current directory

> Does mktemp -d and tempfile -d do the same ? If so , can someone
>   please illustrate its usage with an example.

It does not consider contents, it creates a random name and makes sure there is no such directory:

```
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
cd $tmpdir
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see `tempfile` on a standard Linux system, and I'm not familiar with the command.

In the old days, we simply appended `$$` at the end of file and directory names:

```
  mkdir "mydir.$$"
```

But, mktemp replaces that with a much more secure and safer method.

Usage is generally:

```
 $ my_temp_dir=$(mktemp -d -tmpdir=$temp_dir -t $template)
```

The `$template` is optional. It allows you to set a name. A template contains a series of `XXX` which the program can use to guarantee a unique name. If you don't specify `$temp_dir`, it will generally put the directory under `/tmp`.

The syntax takes advantage that `mktemp` creates a temporary directory and then echos out the name. Thus, you can capture the name of the temporary directory created.